# Algebraic derivatives of a given function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

I was studying about fractional derivatives and after that did some own work on imaginary order derivatives. Now I'm curious to know are algebraic order derivatives possible?
Like the xth derivative of x.

Comment: yes you can do it as we know the derivative operator in linear

Comment: I neither get the question nor this comment. What is an derivative of algebraic order? Do you have a specific definition in mind? What has linearity of differentiation to do with this question or even rational derivatives?

Comment: Do you mean something like $\frac{d^{(x)}\;\;f(x)}{d^{(x)}x}$ where $f(x)=x$

Comment: yeah that is what I had in my mind, but not only for x maybe further polynomials or expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing my comment:

You should notice how this is an entirely new structure. As when we differentiate we usually do it a $\mathbb{N_+}$ - [integer] amount of times. Now people generalized this idea to the $\mathbb{Q}$ - [rational numbers], $\mathbb{R}$ - [reals] or even $\mathbb{C}$ - [complex numbers]. The common idea is numbers. But the core concept stems from a discrete amount of operations.

But [x] is not a number. It can be a function or an indexing letter or a parameter. Now when you differentiate a function $f(x)$ you don't just take it at one point (like $x_0$) . You try to find its derivative on an **as big domain as possible** (often $\mathbb{R}$ and its varieties).

If you want to to differentiate $[x]$ amount of times while $x$ is going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (so the domain being $\mathbb{R}$ presumably) then you'll have to find a different kind of derivative for every single point and you'll run into some problems.

Using the original idea, you'd need to calculate a lot.

Namely $$\text{card}(\mathbb{R})=\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$$

amount of times. You can imagine $\aleph_0$ as how many rationals are there. So you'd need to calculate an exponential amount.

Of course this logic is rather the computer science side of the problem. You could just design a new structure where the derivative-operator continously changes as we shift through the reals. But figuring out that is rather your job.

Specify your question so we can give you a better answer!

Comment: could you tell me where I could study more on it? I was just curious on thr subject and wish to study more. I'm not able to find much on the internet

Comment: If you know basic calculus pretty well i think you should get a good grip on fractional calculus first. So you actually understand what you are calculating. Then linear algebra to see why linear operators are so important and why nonlinearity is a problem. Your idea is fairly novel and specific so i don't really think i could refer you to anything that works with this kind of structure, well not to my knowledge at least.

Comment: I think the problem is even you don't understand what you want. First try to construct this thing on paper. Make a notation, a proper stucture that has no paradoxes, be able to demonstrate a few functions and graphs. And then post it to mathoverflow or some similar forum (not a problem solving place).

Comment: Your question is abstract in the sense as if you asked 'What if vectors were curved?' or 'What if vectors had always the same dimension as their length?. These sentences are quite genereic to be answered simply. My advice for you to is get a good grasp on calcs, lin alg, maybe differential geometry.

Comment: If i piqued your interest with my explanation, if you want to compare different kind of infinities like how both there are infinite amount of natural numbers and real numbers but there are more reals than naturals then you can just look up 'Cardinality' on wikipedia or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88), it's rather informal but i think is a good introduction to the topic.